# Catch key press when using unEnglish inputmethod in MFC

Tags: mfc, internationalization, keypress

Recently, I am doing some research on i18n. I found that some non-English input method is different with English method in keyboard event. I tried to catch key press by overriding `PreTranslateMessage` method. But it doesn't work for Chinese and Russia input method. These method don't call `PreTranslateMessage`  method. Does anyone know some solution for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I assume English and non-English refers to ANSI versus Unicode. You can show some code to improve the question.

Comment: Could you show your PreTranslateMessage at least? When it doesn't work?

Comment: can't you just use WM_KEYDOWN? you can check if ctrl, shift, alt or other keys are pressed too

Comment: `PreTranslateMessage` is only ever called, when the application is not in a modal message loop. A nested message loop is created, when the UI shows a modal dialog, or is moved/sized, for example. If your `PreTranslateMessage` isn't called, you are in a nested message loop.